# Path variables in CMake

Tags: c++, makefile, cmake

Trying to convert a makefile project to CMake. In my makefile I have something like this:

```
MY_PATH := ../../../../..

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := main.cpp \
    $(MY_PATH)/AlertIcon.cpp
```

but the following doesn't work in CMake:

```
set(MY_PATH, "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/../../../../..")

add_library(mylib SHARED
            main.cpp
            ${MY_PATH}/AlertIcon.cpp)
```

What is the proper syntax?

Comment: XY problem. What is a source file doing five levels *up* from your project? And what is the error you're seeing? What does "doesn't work" mean?

Comment: You don't have a main() function in a library, so why do you have a main.cpp?

Comment: This is just an example, not my real makefile, of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `set(MY_PATH "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/../../../../..")` it should be no comma between arguments.

See [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.12/command/set.html).

Also, you can use `message(${MY_PATH})` to "debug" variable values.

Comment: You are absolutely awesome, thank you. I'm surprised it did not throw an error on the 'set' line.
Extra points for the message() command!